# How to hide using C\C++ with Show hidden Files and Folder enabled

Tags: c++, c, windows, file

I would like to know how to programmatically hide a file but making the file or folder still hidden with Show hidden files and folders enabled from the Tools->Folder options of Explorer.

Comment: Save the only copy of the file onto removable media (USB drive, floppy, etc) and lock the media in a safe.  For extra security, bury the safe at the bottom of a deep lake.  Now you can set up your hidden files options all you want, but it won't show up.

Comment: Since you refer to "Tools->Folder options of Explorer", I assume that this is for Microsoft Windows, and I have tagged it appropriately.  This sort of thing is very platform-dependent.  Since it's a large security hole if it exists, it's likely to be specific only to certain versions, and any solution you find is likely to be wiped out by a later patch.

Comment: Related: [How is a file/folder “fully” hidden in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5049356).

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this is not possible as it would be a security vulnerability (programs could place unknown files on your hard drive that you couldn't see or delete).

Even Windows system files are visible.

Answer (score 4):

There is NO user mode API to make files hidden from 'show hidden files', and it's a good thing to.

The only way to do this is to get your code to run in the kernel.  The [rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_CD_copy_protection_scandal) that Sony "accidently" installed on user machines a couple years ago when they were trying to prevent CDs from being rippable could do it. But there is no *legitimate* use for the ability to hide files from system administrators and power users.

Answer (score 3):

You want the SetFileAttributes function available by #include'ing Windows.h: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535%28VS.85%29.aspx

In code:

```
BOOL result = SetFileAttributes(L"c:\path\to\file", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
```

As for keeping a file hidden from the "show hidden files" option, that's much more difficult and I can't think of a legitimate reason to do it - the only programs that do are rootkits for nefarious purposes.

Comment: As far as I can tell that only sets the file as "hidden" but if you have "Show hidden files and folders" enabled the file will still be visible in Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a file system filter driver. But since you have to ask - just don't do it. Not trying to be rude here, it's just that that is a task that is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

As many have said before, there's no straightforward way to fully 'hide' a file like that.

If you can accept not truly hiding the file but merely obfuscating it, you can always embed it inside a dummy file.  Take the file you want to hide, build a container file to hold it, and name that dummy file with a random name.  For example, you could place the real file's filename starting at offset 512 of the dummy file and place the file's contents starting at offset 1024, inserting 64 bytes of random data every 1KB.  Pad the end with empty space out to the nearest multiple of 4KB, fill the empty space with random bytes, and generate a random sequence of characters to use for a filename.  Now, you can "hide" the file while it's still visible in the filesystem.

However, that's merely "[security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)" and can be defeated by a clever attacker with a hex editor.

If you're simply trying to make sure a file isn't visible to the casual filesystem browser, you can always compress the file, encrypt it, and randomize the filename.  If you need to be able to access/execute the file as-is while it is "hidden", then you're probably (hopefully) out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This program is used to show all hidden files and folder in your system drive and it can run well even system has affected by virus and worms, usually, some kinds of the virus change your files and folders in a hidden state, this script will help you to view your files and folders again. The main feature is without installation it can play.

Please find the source code from my tech blog - http://www.algonuts.info/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-using-c.html

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<dir.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

struct ffblk vfile;
unsigned long int udata;
char ch,present[MAXPATH];

int next_directory(char *);
void scan_directory(char *);

char base[]="X:\\";

using namespace std;

int main(int account,char *arg[],char *env[])
{   
    clrscr();
    getcwd(present,MAXPATH);

    DIR *dir; 
    struct dirent *temp;
    cout<<"\nWelcome to Unhidden for identify the hidden files";
    cout<<"\n\nEnter drive:";
    cin>>ch;

    base[0]=ch;
    if((dir = opendir(base)) == NULL)
    { 
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\nError : Derive not found ";
        getch(); 
        exit(0); 
    }

    scan_directory(base);
    while((temp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        char  *directory = (char *) malloc(3+strlen(temp->d_name)+1);
        strcpy(directory,base);
        strcat(directory,temp->d_name);
        next_directory(directory);
        free(directory);
    }
    closedir(dir);

    clrscr();
    cout<<"\nSystem: Successfully Unhidden it";
    sleep(3);

    return 0;
}

int next_directory(char *path)
{
    int count=0;
    DIR *dirtemp; 
    char *hold,*temp;
    struct dirent *ptemp;  

    hold=path;
    if ((dirtemp = opendir(path)) != NULL)
    scan_directory(path);
    else
    return 0;

    while((ptemp = readdir(dirtemp)) != NULL)
    {     
        char *directory = (char *) malloc(1+strlen(ptemp->d_name)+1);
        directory[0]='\\';
        strcpy(directory+1,ptemp->d_name);
        if(directory[1]!='\.')
        {
            count=strlen(hold);
            temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(hold)+strlen(directory)+1);
            strcpy(temp,hold);
            strcat(temp,directory);
            free(directory);
            if(opendir(temp)!=NULL)
            next_directory(temp); 
            temp[count]='\0'; 
            hold=temp;
        }
        else
        free(directory);
    }
    closedir(dirtemp);
    return 0;
}

void scan_directory(char *tempo)
{
    cout<<"\n"<<tempo;
    unsigned count;
    if(present[0]==tempo[0])
    chdir(tempo);  
    else
    {
        setdisk(tempo[0]-65);
        chdir(tempo); 
    }

    udata = findfirst("*.*",&vfile,0x02);
    while(!udata)
    {  
        _dos_getfileattr(vfile.ff_name,&count);
        if (count & _A_HIDDEN)
        {
            _dos_getfileattr(vfile.ff_name,&count);
            count=count & 248;
            _dos_setfileattr(vfile.ff_name,count);
        }
        udata=findnext(&vfile);
    }

    if(present[0]==tempo[0])    
    system("cd\\");
    chdir(present); 
}
```