# How is a file/folder "fully" hidden in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, directory, hidden

A year ago I was investigating into being secretive and hiding/encrypting data when I came across a program(can't remember its name). It basically hid any file or folder and it could not be discovered by unsetting the attributes of hidden in windows explorer.

How do you think the program did this? Is there a way to make your own program to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the `attrib +s +h +r etc85` command that's posted all over the Internet?

Comment: Wow thanks that must be it. Though wouldn't the folder be visible in other OS's like Linux etc.?

Comment: Yes. It's also not "fully" hidden in Windows... It's just better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this sound like what you were looking for?

http://lifehacker.com/#!249289/download-of-the-day-free-hide-folders-windows

Answer (score 1):

### How to really hide your folders:

1. Click start
2. Click Run
3. Type "cmd" without quotes and clikc ok
4. type "cd PATH TO FILE" example "cd c:\users\shereef\private" hit enter (return key)
5. type attrib +s +h +r FILENAME

Thats it! your folder is now completely hidden from all users in all possible ways.

reference: http://www.sizlopedia.com/2008/10/26/hide-folders-windows/

Comment: your instructions look like *literal* instructions because the example file being hidden `etc85` is not in the same path example. that is why I downvoted and that is why this is poorly done. just delete it

Comment: @defaye Only a beginner would delete an answer, even if it is truly poorly written, because it may help someone one day, but deleted it doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on start and find `cmd`, then right click and run it as
   administrator.
2. Fetch the directory that you wish to hide and copy it to the
   clipboard.
3. Change to that directory in command prompt e.g. `cd C:\path\to\x` *You can use right mouse click to paste in the copied path.*
   (Note: if it is on another disk, change to that drive by typing `F:` and pressing enter)
4. To make a folder `x` invisible (*if `x` is a folder*), change directory to the parent of
   `x` e.g. `cd ..`
5. Then write the commands: `attrib +r +h +s x`
6. To reverse the process simply `attrib -r -h -s x`